# Mongoose find only those who have an entry in another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to find entry in a collection using mongoose, but I want only entries which have an entry in another collection.

**To be more specific:**
I have a collection 'post'

```
    var postSchema = new Schemas({
    postedBy:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    group:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group'},
    postContent: String
});
```

a collection 'group':

```
    var groupSchema = new Schemas({
    name: String,
    creator:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    interes: String,
    public: Boolean
});
```

and a collection 'groupMember':

```
var groupMemeberSchema = new Schemas({
    group:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group'},
    user:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
```

What I want is to retrieve all post from groups that the user is a member in.

Something like:

```
    groupmembers.find({user: req.user._id}, (err, groupsThatTheUserIn) => {
        post.find(({$where: this.group EXIST_IN(groupsThatTheUserIn)}, (err, posts) => {
            res.json(posts);
    }))

})
```

But their is no exist_in() function in mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve all post from groups that the user is a member in, you can use the aggregation framework where **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** is at your disposal to join the related collections with a single query.

For example, running the following aggregate operation will return the desired posts:

```
groupmembers.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "user": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
           "from": "posts",
           "localField": "group”,
           "foreignField": "group",
           "as": "posts"  
        }
    },
    {  
], (err, results) => res.json(results[0].posts))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In fact their is no need to join "groups", "posts" alone did the job.

Comment: @davdsb You are absolutely correct, will update my answer